# what are the difference between 'learn' and 'study'?

Tags: word-choice

Should I be when to use 'learn' and  not 'study'?

eg. " I am learning  how to love a person. " is right ?

Or , i should say:"I am studying how to love a person."

I understand, thank you everyone!

Comment: The [ell.se] site may be of interest to you. While both terms can be translated as 学 in Chinese, they are quite different in English.

Comment: You may study and not learn; you may learn without study. You don't supply enough context to tell which word would be the best choice for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Learning" is general.

"Studying" tends to be focused learning by watching or reading.  Studying specifically involves learning with your eyes but not your hands.

Examples:

- I'm studying to drive a car.  (reading the manual, not hands-on)
- I'm learning to drive a car.  (includes all aspects of learning,
  including hands-on)

Comment: @sis : Your'e welcome.

Comment: What about "learning to read"?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly **study** refers to some paper or book stuff **ex.reading manual or something** on your own and learning refers to practical implementation with some other things related to activity or particular thing on that you are going to put your hands-on. You can **learn** your own as well from someone. You can **study** your own and not from anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You study a subject with the aim to learn something of that subject.

Examples:

- "I am studying physics so that I can learn how the universe works."
- "I am learning about humans by studying philosophy."
- "I am studying birds so that I can learn how to fly."
- "I have learnt how to ride a bike by studying cycling."
- "I am learning how to love a person"
- "I am studying love"

Answer (score 0):

*Study* relates to the (mechanistic) activity, while *learning* relates to the actual acquisition of the skill or knowledge.

> **Study**
> transitive verb
> 1:  to read in detail especially with the intention of learning - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/study)
>
> **Learn**
> to gain knowledge or skill by studying, practicing, being taught, or experiencing something - [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/learn)

**Example**

> Having the TV on at a high volume while studying really hampers learning.